# Maybe not the best answer, but still trying to help? Answering questions to help and not for points

Tags: discussion

I can already feel the down votes, but I wanted to ask the community about answering questions on stackoverflow regardless.

Today I made my first attempt to try to help another poster because I thought I could help seeing how I thought I knew where I could find the answer (before he edited his post to show he already tried the method). I would have liked to post the resource I found as a comment, since I knew it wasn't really an answer provided by me, but I could not since I have very few reputation points mostly from accepting answers not answering them. So I "answered" with what I thought he could use st.replace() method and the link where I found the topic and saying that I would have commented but could not. After I posted it, the OP had edited it to show he had tried the method.

I didn't realize that I would be fiercely attacked for this attempt. Both being called a fool for using w3school has the resource link (didn't realize it was so hated) and a thinly veiled insult for being a points-digger. I ended up deleting my answer since it was so hated but here's a screenshot [image: screenshot]

When did it become a crime to try and help? I know i'm not a professional programmer (my profile says novice) but I usually find it better to receive an answer then to sit for days with no leads at all. Is there a way to send a private msg with help, is that even an option? I don't feel I would even try answering another question in the future.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: Downvotes don't make you a criminal. Don't take downvotes personally. You are free to try and help, but if the answer you posted is actually not helpful, it can be downvoted. Take into account that *others will read your question* and if they are novices too, they trust that the voting has indicated how much they can trust the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367347/replace-x-with-y-and-y-with-x-in-a-single-regular-expression

This was the question. The OP edited the post to show he had tried the str.replace function seconds after I posted my suggestion. So I understand the first comment. 

I don't find the downvotes so much as the attacks

Comment: If the information really is relevant, important, and useful someone else will post it. The exception is if you have specialized, unusual knowledge. If you do know an answer post it, but don't worry about not being able to comment - just go on to another question.

Comment: Just a note: "Hope it helps!" and "-DD" are unhelpful noise. They might have been a factor in the downvotes.

Comment: It is unfortunate the OP added his own try with `replace` after you posted. It may have been better not to start with the "I cannot comment" sentence, and also not "Maybe you can.." - you could have *stated* "Use `str.replace`. On recommending w3schools.com ... yes, I've been there, done that, have been told off. Never did it again.

Answer (score 9):

First off, don't admit in your post that you believe that you're doing something that you shouldn't.  That's just inviting people to downvote you.

As it turns out, `string.replace` wasn't what the OP was looking for, but if it was a valid solution, then telling the OP to use it, and posting a link to it would be just fine.

You should also try to explain in your answer how to use `string.replace()` to solve the OP's problem.  Don't rely on the link to do that for you.  The link might get broken a year or 2 in the future.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to post a comment you need to post a comment, rather than posting an answer as a comment.

Since you don't yet have enough reputation to comment you will need to refrain from commenting until you have earned that right by posting *actual* answers (or contributing in other ways enough to be considered trustworthy enough to comment).

There is no private messaging system.  One of the primary features of the site is that any answers given are vetted by the community, to mitigate the problems of low quality answers, and also that answers ought to not just be for the person asking the question, but for all readers.  Giving answers privately is contrary to both of these core goals.

Comment: That i can understand, thank you for your response. But I feel that this might be preventing people from giving leads or possible solutions. I know that I have a question about a topic that's not very well represented on stackoverflow, and has been left unanswered for some days. I would have appreciated any hints.

Comment: @DanceDreamer And you'll be able to do that when you're able to earn the right to do so.  Only a few mediocre posts is entirely sufficient to earn that right.

Comment: @DanceDreamer giving people leads is only useful if they lead to information that the OP wants.  If they don't, then you're just wasting the OP's time and your own.  Leads that don't result in anything actively make finding a solution to a problem harder.